# How to change value in columns 4,5,6 of a dataframe to percentage format?

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

I use the following code to try to change value in columns 4,5,6 of a dataframe to percentage format but it returned me the errors.

```
df.iloc[:,4:7].apply('{:.2%}'.format)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`DataFrame.applymap`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'a':list('abcdef'),
         'b':list('aaabbb'),
         'c':[4,5,4,5,5,4],
         'd':[7,8,9,4,2,3],
         'e':[1,3,5,7,1,0],
         'e':[5,3,6,9,2,4],
         'f':[7,8,9,4,2,3],
         'g':[1,3,5,7,1,0],
         'h':[7,8,9,4,2,3],
         'i':[1,3,5,7,1,0]

})


df.iloc[:,4:7] = df.iloc[:,4:7].applymap('{:.2%}'.format)
print (df)
   a  b  c  d        e        f        g  h  i
0  a  a  4  7  500.00%  700.00%  100.00%  7  1
1  b  a  5  8  300.00%  800.00%  300.00%  8  3
2  c  a  4  9  600.00%  900.00%  500.00%  9  5
3  d  b  5  4  900.00%  400.00%  700.00%  4  7
4  e  b  5  2  200.00%  200.00%  100.00%  2  1
5  f  b  4  3  400.00%  300.00%    0.00%  3  0
```